# What is the .NET version of the PollingDuplexBindingElement?

Tags: .net, wcf, silverlight-4.0

What is the .NET version of Silverlight's PollingDuplexBindingElement?

Answer (score 1):

I think `CompositeDuplexBindingElement` is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on which binding you're using. If you use the TCP or named pipes transport, you don't really need any binding element to support duplex contracts - they're inherently duplex. If you're using HTTP, which is inherently a request/reply protocol, then you need some other binding element like the CompositeDuplexBindingElement as suggested by @vcsjones.